# Anomalies when trying to fit student's t distribution using scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statsmodels

I am trying to fit a t distribution to some data that I have. In order to test it out I first tried to generate a sample from a fixed distribution and try to fit on it. Below is the code that I am using.

```
samp = t.rvs(loc=0, scale=0.6, df=1.3, size=150)

param = t.fit(samp)

x = linspace(-5,5,100)

pdf_fitted = t.pdf(x,loc=param[0],scale=param[1],df=param[2])
pdf = t.pdf(x,loc=0,scale=0.6,df=1.3)

title('Student\'s t Distribution')
plot(x,pdf_fitted,'r-',x,pdf,'b-')
hist(samp, normed=1,alpha=0.3)
show()
print(param)
```

Now, one would expect that `pdf` and `pdf_fitted` be essentially the same. However, that is not the case. When the plots are shown the original and fitted distributions look very different. Moreover, the parameters obtained do not match the ones specified (loc=0, scale=0.6, df=1.3) at all! This confuses me because I am simply adapting the code from http://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/07/distribution-fitting-with-scipy.html to work with t distributions. Can someone tell me if there are any nuances with fitting t distributions? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fit` method of `scipy.stats.t` returns `(df, loc, scale)`, so this line

```
pdf_fitted = t.pdf(x,loc=param[0],scale=param[1],df=param[2])
```

should be

```
pdf_fitted = t.pdf(x, loc=param[1], scale=param[2], df=param[0])
```

The example that you linked to uses the normal distribution, which doesn't have an additional shape parameter, so in that case, `param[0]` is the location and `param[1]` is the scale.

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected now. It's unfortunate that the documentation does not mention what order they are in. I suppose in retrospect the function signature `(x, df, loc, scale)` should have been a hint.